# You do not have permission to perform this action when accessing api in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

i am trying to add custom permissions in my Django app using Django rest framework. i created an API n tested it in postman it works fine for authenticated user. however it doesnt display details when i visit details view . for example when i visit http://localhost:8000/placeslist/ it displays all the places but when i try http://localhost:8000/placeslist/1/ it says you dont have permission. i dont know where i went wrong

**models.py**

```
class Places(BaseModel):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,default='')
  owner=models.ForeignKey('auth.User',related_name='place_list',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class PlacesView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Places.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlacesSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner)

    def perform_create(self,serializer):
      serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)


class PlacesDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Places.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlacesSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner)
```

**Permission.py**

```
class IsOwner(BasePermission):
  def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Places):
        return obj.owner == request.user       
    return obj.owner == request.user
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class PlacesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
  class Meta:
    model = Places
    fields =('id','name','owner')
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^placeslist/$', PlacesView.as_view(), name="place"),
url(r'placeslist/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',PlacesDetailView.as_view(), 
name="place_details"),
url(r'^get-token/', obtain_auth_token),
```

**Settings.py**

```
....

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
)
}

....
```

Answer (score 7):

That's because of your custom permission where you a trying to access an instance (Place with pk = 1) where the owner is not the user you are currently using.

Check the owner of that Place.

And you can just remove the `permissions.IsAuthenticated` on your view, because you already put it in the default permission class.

Comment: make sure your settings DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES are set properly in settings.py file

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't link my new ViewSet in urls.py so the request was going to some other API which had a different permission class.
You can put a debugger in restframework's code and see what happens.